# Regex pattern for specific format

Tags: regex

I'm not really good at regex or I can say that I'm a totally beginner to it. I want to know the regex from the following format:

1. LB-[0-999] - "LB-" with 0 - 999 digits and no spaces at the beginning, middle, and end.
2. XX-[0-19999] - Only two  Capitalize letters in any combination with "-" and 0-19999 digits and no spaces at the beginning, middle and end.
3. XXX-[0-19999] - Only three Capitalize letters in any combination with "-" and 0-19999 digits and no spaces at the beginning, middle and end.

I want to get all three patterns but I'm really new to regex. I was planning to use it as html5 input validation and I'm really out of time of studying it.

This is what I tried so far:

```
^LB-[0-9]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/LB\-[0-9]{1,3}/
/[A-Z]{2}\-1?[0-9]{1,4}/
/[A-Z]{3}\-1?[0-9]{1,4}/
```

With [0-9] you make appear only numbers in this set: 0 until 9 and with [A-Z] only capital letter from alphabeta. In {1,3} and {1,4} you make obligated to have at least one letter/number and at most four or three. With `?1` you make optional the present of a number 1 before your number, that will be present only for 10000 number or greater. This are three different er for each one of your possible entries.

Consider the changes prosed by user in his last comment the code will be like this:

```
/LB\-(00[1-9] | [1-9][0-9] | [1-9][0-9]{2})/
/[A-Z]{2}\-(0000[1-9] | 000[1-9][0-9] | 00[1-9][0-9]{2} | 0[1-9][0-9]{3} | 1[0-9][0-9]{3})/
/[A-Z]{3}\-(0000[1-9] | 000[1-9][0-9] | 00[1-9][0-9]{2} | 0[1-9][0-9]{3} | 1[0-9][0-9]{3})/
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit your pattern?

Comment: You put the question mark at the wrong place.

Comment: I agree Casimir, thanks. Now it is fixed.

Comment: To be more clear: `/[A-Z]{2}-1?[0-9]{1,4}/`

Comment: Can you make the pattern 1 take only 3 digits and starts with `001` and the other two takes 5 digits and starts with `00001`

Comment: Yes, I added the changes in a second code.

Comment: My answer for the 19999 was retarded, I was asleep at the wheel. Deleted it, +1 for you. :)

Comment: One last before I accept the answer please the 2nd pattern to `/[A-Z]{2}\-1?[0-9]{4}[1-9]{1}/` and the last pattern to `/[A-Z]{3}\-1?[0-9]{4}[1-9]{1]/` I was looking for 5 characters for the digits and thank you. You saved my day.

Comment: Right, now I updated the second code block with this changes.

Comment: Hey @user2785929 , I realize that a big change was necessary because of the need to start from 001 and 00001 then I changed the code a little bit using the | operator to make possible different combinations.